# accessing XML file with SimpleXML not working

Tags: php, xml

I have the following xml returned to me when I am making an API call with yahoo weather.  Why is it I get a blank when I echo out $out?

```
 $endpoint = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%3D%20560743&diagnostics=true';


 $xml = simplexml_load_file($endpoint) or die('failed to load xml');
 $out = $xml -> query -> diagnostics -> publiclyCallable;

 echo $out;
```

RETURNED XML:

```
 This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
 <query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="2017-02-10T11:54:56Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">

 <diagnostics>
    <publiclyCallable>true</publiclyCallable>
    <url execution-start-time="1" execution-stop-time="7" execution-time="6">...</url>
    <user-time>8</user-time>
    <service-time>6</service-time>
    <build-version>2.0.92</build-version>
 </diagnostics>
 <results>...</results>
 </query>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `query` as `$xml` already represents it:

```
$endpoint = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%3D%20560743&diagnostics=true';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($endpoint) or die('failed to load xml');
$out = $xml -> diagnostics -> publiclyCallable;
echo $out;    // `true`
```

Answer (score 0):

The XML seems to be invalid, remove the first line before passing the received string to

> simplexml_load_file()

function